# Standard(s) for client-side definition of advanced search?

Tags: sql

Is there some kind of established standard or search-meta-language for defining advanced search? Some defined standard for the use of wildcards, logical operators, labels or categories etc.?

Something like Googles possibility to use "OR", "+" etc for logical definitions, "label:news" for specifying a category etc.?

(This client-side "meta-language" will later be translated to an server-side sql query. If there are established solutions for this translations, that's of course interesting too!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem to have open-source to-SQL conversion libraries in abundance, but maybe CQL would work for you? http://zing.z3950.org/cql/intro.html

Comment: Thank you, njk! :-)
Exactly what I had in mind.
Now, let's find out what php implementations there are...